# How to extract portion of a line in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have a line say

> line = "start running at Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"

and I want to extract

> "Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"

I tried this...

```
line = "start running at Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"
if (line =~ /start running at/)
   line.split("start running at ").last
end
```

... but is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: That's readable and efficient. I wouldn't change it just for the sake of changing it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way to extract, from an arbitrary string, a substring that represents a time in the given format. I've assumed there is at most one such substring in the string.

```
require 'time'

R = /
    (?:#{Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.join('|')})\s
              # match day name abbreviation in non-capture group. space
    (?:#{Date::MONTHNAMES[1,12].join('|')})\s
              # match month name in non-capture group, space
    \d{1,2}\s # match one or two digits, space
    \d{2}:    # match two digits, colon
    \d{2}:    # match two digits, colon
    \d{2}\s   # match two digits, space
    \d{4}     # match 4 digits
    (?!\d)    # do not match digit (negative lookahead)
    /x        # free-spacing regex def mode
  # /
  #  (?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\s
  #   (?:January|February|March|...|November|December)\s
  # \d{1,2}\s
  # \d{2}:
  # \d{2}:
  # \d{2}\s
  # \d{4}
  # (?!\d)
  # /x
```

```
def extract_time(str)
  s = str[R]
  return nil if s.nil?
  (DateTime.strptime(s, "%a %B %e %H:%M:%S %Y") rescue nil) ? s : nil
end

str = "start eating breakfast at Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"
extract_time(str)
  #=> "Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017" 

str = "go back to sleep at Cat April 1 07:30:37 2017"
extract_time(str)
  #=> nil
```

Alternatively, if there is a match against `R`, but [Time#strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) raises an exception (meaning `s` is not a valid time for the given time format) one could raise an exception to advise the user.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
line.sub(/start running at (.*)/, '\1')
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this with regular expressions would be:

```
if md = line.match(/start running at (.*)/)
  md[1]
end
```

But you don't need regular expressions, you can do regular string operations:

```
prefix = 'start running at '
if line.start_with?(prefix)
  line[prefix.size..-1]
end
```

Comment: ...or use the penultimate form of [String#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D): `line[/start running at (.*)/, 1] #=> "Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (as it turns out, slightly faster) option using [#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-partition):

```
# will return empty string if there is no match, instead of raising an exception like split.last will
line.partition('start running at ').last
```

I was interested how this performs against regexp match, so here's a quick benchmark with 1 million executions each:

```
line.sub(/start running at (.*)/, '\1')
# => @real=1.7465

line.partition('start running at ').last
# => @real=0.712406
# => this is faster, but you'd need to be calling this quite a bit for it to make a significant difference
```

---

**Bonus**: it also makes it really easy to cater for a more general case e.g. if you have lines that start with *"start running at"* and others that start with *"stop running at"*. Then something like `line.partition(' at ').last` will cater for both (and actually run slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest would be `line["Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"]` which would return your "Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017" string if present and nil if not.
The [] notation on a String is a shorthand for getting a substring out of the string and can be used with another string or a Regular Expression. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

In case the string is unknown you can use this shorthand also like Cary suggested

```
line[/start running at (.*)/, 1]
```

In case you want to be sure the date extracted is valid you would need the regular expression from his answer but you still could use this method.

Comment: If you know exactly which substring you want as output, what's the point of even looking for it?

Comment: @Eric, that's not quite accurate. This tells you if a string contains a given substring, but your point is well-taken.

Comment: @EricDuminil it's exactly what the OP asked for, in this case it is a way to check if the String contains the substring

Comment: I don't think so : OP wants to checks if the string contains `"start running at "` and if that's the case, extract what's coming after. It could be `"Sat April 1 07:30:37 2017"`, it could be something else. Is `puts 7` a valid answer to the question "How do I add 4 and 3?".

Comment: It's unclear from the question itself, I added another version for the case that..

Answer (score 0):

And yet another alternative:

```
puts $1 if line =~ /start running at (.*)/
```